# Account/Password Distribution Tool - stuck creating an object from csv

Tags: python, class, passwords

I am fairly new to python programming and after finishing a bunch of beginners trainings id like to get some hands on experience.

My idea was to develop a account/password distribution tool.

What it should do is:

1. Import csv with accounts, users, permissions (Username1,Account1-PasswordPart1, Account2-PasswordPart2)
2. iterate through accounts.csv (generate and attach pw to account object)
3. iterate through users.csv (generate encrypted zip with *.txt for each users that contains accounts and half the password based on the permissions.csv)

**1. Import**

The import was fairly easy to implement.

**2. Generate Password**

This is the function I use to generate the passwords:

```
def pw_generator(length):
    #define data
    lower = string.ascii_lowercase
    upper = string.ascii_uppercase
    num = string.digits
    symbols = string.punctuation
    #string.ascii_letters
    
    #combine the data
    all = lower + upper + num + symbols
    
    #use random 
    randompw = random.sample(all,length)
    
    #create the password 
    password = "".join(randompw)
    
    #print the password
    return password
```

**3. Use accounts.csv and make an object out of it**

This is were im currently stuck. I tried this .. (and many other approaches)

```
class account:
    def __init__(self,accountname,password):
        self.accountname = accountname
        self.password = password


acc_list = []
with open('accounts.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(reader, None)  # Skip the header.
    for accountname, password in reader:
        acc_list.append(account(account, password))
        account.password=pw_generator(16)
        print(accountname, account.password)
```

This gives me a list of the accountnames and passwords but I dont see how i can use them afterwards as an array..

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you have dug yourself a hole by giving a class a lowercase name.

This thing:

```py
        acc_list.append(account(account, password))
```

If you rename the `class account` into `class Account` and refactor the code, you'll see that it doesn't make any sense:

```py
        acc_list.append(Account(Account, password))
```

You create an instance of a class `Account` by giving it the class `Account` as an `accountname`. It doesn't seem like the thing you want to do.

And then you also change an undeclared class attribute (not the instance attribute, but the class attribute!):

```py
     Account.password=pw_generator(16)
```

Which also looks extremely suspicious, to put it mildly.

Second, it's not obvious what the field `password` should be in the end. Is it the value you read from `.csv`? Or some autogenerated pw?

You probably wanted to do something like this:

```py
    for accountname, password in reader:
        acc_instance = Account(accountname, password)  # Create an instance
        acc_list.append(acc_instance)  # add the instance to the list
        print(acc_instance.accountname, acc_instance.password)  # print the instance

    # Then you can do whatever you like with the list.
    # For example you could redefine all passwords in all accounts and print new credentials:
    for acc in acc_list:
        acc.password = pw_generator(16)
        print(acc.accountname, acc.password)
    # Or save this list in whatever form you like.
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response. I managed to make it work for myself but I would love to get some feedback and also improve the script a bit. Something is still a little messed up but you can see the current status here: https://github.com/thoyoo/acc_distribution_tool.git

Comment: @daveyo Okay, buddy, you're still insisting on using non-capitalised classnames and you also have three for loops embedded into each other. You gotta untangle you logic and understand yourself what you are trying to accomplish.